# TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple) || website blocking code in python

Tags: python

I'm trying a website blocking program in python

TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

I am getting this error when I try the below code. Can someone please help me fix it?

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt

if dt((dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 19)) < dt.now() < dt(
        (dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 21)):
    pass
```

Comment: assuming that `dt` is a datetime instance, you have extra parenthesis. `dt(dt.now().year, dt.now().month, dt.now().day, 19)` and similarly later.

Comment: What is the purpose of the double parentheses?  `if dt((...`

Answer (score 2):

You have extra parentheses in both date comparisons:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt

now = dt.now()
if dt(now.year, now.month, now.day, 19) < now < dt(now.year, now.month, now.day, 21):
    pass
```